# Is there a reliable way to record user initiated facebook apprequests?

Tags: facebook

It seems like the only way to do `apprequests` from user to user is via a dialogue. It also seem like I would need to do a ajax post with the invite ids to my server to record them happening. It's a bit unreliable.

Is there a way where I can get a list of the requests without needing to do a post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only list pending requests by calling `/me/apprequests` on the user. Any other requests that were processed, you need to save them at the initial point of the request.